# If $a, b, c$ are integers then $a + b + c$ is even if and only if $0$ or two of $a, b, c$ are odd.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-verification

I attempted to prove this by contrapositive but was not sure if that is the most efficient way to do so. Any feedback would be greatly appreciated.

Prove: If a, b, c are integers then a + b + c is even if and only if
0 or two of a, b, c are odd.

Comment: Yes, contrapositive is fine. That means one or three of $a,b,c$ are odd. If they are all odd, then the sum is odd. If one is odd and two are even, then the sum is odd.

Comment: There are only $4$ possibilities altogether; $0$ odd sumands, $1$ odd summand, $2$ odd sumands, or $3$ odd summands. See what happens.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can also reason directly: suppose $k$ of the 3 numbers are odd (so $k=0,1,2,3$). Then $3-k$ are even. So modulo 2 we have as the sum: $k \cdot 1 + (3-k) \cdot 0  = k$. This can only be even (i.e. $0$ modulo $2$) if $k$ is, so $k = 0$ or $k=2$. This directly generalises to the sum of $n$ numbers as well.